# A Checkstyle Rule for OpenJDK's Local Variable Type Inference Style Guidelines

Tags: java, checkstyle, java-10

## Background:

OpenJDK have released a [style guide](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) for local variable type inference.

I was looking for a checkstyle built in rule that addresses it but didn't found one.

What I'm trying to get is pretty simple but I'm not that familiar with writing custom Modules.

## Example:

#### Allow:

- instance creation, it's clear what's being created

```java
var something = new Anything(); // OK
```

- it's a literal, it's obvious what type it has

```java
var something = "literal"; // OK
```

#### Violation:

- even with good naming, no clue what's the type

```java
var something = anything.doAnything(); // Violation
```

- it improves readability to use var here

```java
Anything<Foo<Bar>> something = new Anything<>(); // Violation
```

- not a big deal but just for consistency

```java
String something = "literal"; // Violation
```

## Question:

Is there any existing rule I can extend / tweak to get the above? Should I try writing my own rule? I assume RegExp can handle some cases but not all.

Comment: *Should I try writing my own rule* - why not

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak this one :
[image]

find it here : https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/coding/matchxpath.html#MatchXpath

Note : MatchXpath is Since Checkstyle 8.39